# CameraX does not reopen camera

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I am working on a camera app based on the sample CameraX app from Google that can be found on GitHub. Sometimes, when I reopen the app after running in the background, the camera won`t open and the preview screen remains black. When the app is opening the camera, normally the following log is shown:

```
D/PreviewView: Surface requested by Preview.
D/CameraStateRegistry: Recalculating open cameras:
    Camera                                       State                 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Camera@f2ad3fe[id=0]                         OPENING               
    Camera@35c320a[id=1]                         UNKNOWN               
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)
D/CameraStateRegistry: Recalculating open cameras:
    Camera                                       State                 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Camera@f2ad3fe[id=0]                         OPEN                  
    Camera@35c320a[id=1]                         UNKNOWN               
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)
```

However, when the app does not open, only this log is shown:

```
Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 0
D/CameraStateRegistry: Recalculating open cameras:
    Camera                                       State                 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Camera@f2ad3fe[id=0]                         OPENING               
    Camera@35c320a[id=1]                         UNKNOWN               
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)
```

... without the notice that the camera has been opened correctly.
Any idea what is going wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: What is the model of your device?

Comment: I use a Moto G9 Plus. However, since I updated to the CameraX core library '1.0.0-rc01', this issue has never occurred again. Maybe, the update resolved the issue... However, if it happens again I will make sure to amend this comment to let you know. Thanks

Comment: After 6 months, I can confirm that with the CameraX core library update, the issue has been resolved permanently.